How to estimate the standard error of True Positive Rate of a statistical test on simulated data?
Suppose I run a simulation for $N$ iterations. Each iteration generates a dataset of $k$ participants, then a statistical test is applied on the generated dataset to test a hypothesis $H_0$(null) vs $H_1$(alternative), which yields a binary outcome, $1$ or $0$, indicating rejection (and accepting $H_1$), or failing to reject $H_0$,respectively.
Hence, the simulation results in random variables $X_1, X_2 \ldots X_N \in \{0, 1\}$.
Now, assuming that the simulations were generated using the alternative hypothesis $H_1$, then the sample mean $\bar{X} = \frac{\sum X_i}{N}$ gives the True Positive Rate (TPR).
But I'm not sure how to estimate the standard error of TPR. Should I just calculate the standard error of $X_1, X_2 \ldots X_N$, or the standard deviation? In my case, I always get large standard deviations (which is not so surprising since these are binary values).
Any help will be greatly appreciated. I'm new to simulation and bootstrap theory, and any guidance (reference texts) will be very useful!
